# Generics - incompatible types

Tags: java, generics, incompatibility

```
public class HelloWorld{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<? extends Number> callback = new ArrayList<Long>();
    new Container<>().test(callback);
}

public static class Container<T extends Number> {

    public void test(List<T> some) {

    }

}
```

}

this code produces

```
HelloWorld.java:7: error: incompatible types: List<CAP#1> cannot be converted to List<Number>                                                                                                                                                          
        new Container<>().test(callback);                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                               ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    CAP#1 extends Number from capture of ? extends Number
```

Can you explain in details this code incorrect.

I expect that new Container will be generalized with type compatible with callback

Comment: Somewhat pointless, since `String` is a `final` class.

Comment: @Bohemian imagine that it is Number

Comment: In that case, use `Number`, since there are valid reasons to use `Number` in generics but not very many for `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there cannot be a type that extends `String` as `String` is a final class.

Secondly, the compiler cannot determine if the type `? extends SomeType` that you use for your `List` is the same type as `T extends SomeType`  that you use for the `Container` class, so it produces an error.

What you would need to do is either declare a generic type in the method signature, and use that type for both the `List` and `Container`:

```
public <T extends SomeClass> void example() {
    List<T> callback = new ArrayList<>();
    new Container<T>().test(callback);
}
```

Or declare the list with a non-bounded type:

```
List<SomeClass> callback = new ArrayList<>();
new Container<>().test(callback);
```

Comment: yeah, it's true +1

Comment: I think you meant *declare the list with a non-bounded type*, no?

Comment: @Bohemian yes, my bad

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're using generics. as you define Container, it tells to Container default constructor must support a type which is instance of String. 
here is a correct example which String is subClass of Object, so i use that.

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> callback = new ArrayList<String>();
        new Container<String>().test(callback);
    }

    public static class Container<T extends Object> {

        public void test(List<T> some) {

        }

    }
}
```

I hope this helps you.